# How to pass a parameter value to an anchor href into Servlet?

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have two parameters that I need to send over to servlet via anchor href in the line below:

`<a href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Page/Servlet?searchType=searchMethod&searchBy=searchInput">Search</a>`

searchType and searchBy will be what my servlet will store the **searchMethod** and **searchInput**'s value in the servlet. I know how to do this, but **I do not know how to pull that value from searchMethod and searchInput.**

How do I do so? I tried using Javascript, but I'm on a novice level for both Javascript and HTML.

Note: searchMethod is a select value, and searchBy is text value, and Page/Servlet is just temporary name.

Comment: Why are you not using a form tag with a GET method? Whatever values you select will be sent on submit automatically, without the need to build a href

Comment: Can you post your HTML? To understand where those values are coming from.